# Number of combinations to introduce people within certain groups

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, combinations, combinatorial-designs

I am trying to calculate a combination of unique people inside of the different groups. Nonetheless, I have not observed any formula to achieve my intention. There are 4 different groups and each group has 4 people. Besides, the main question here is, what is the total number of combinations that I can introduce to every people by picking one person from each group to a new groups of 4 people? I want every people to meet each other and the total number of enumerations are needed to compute the total solution.

For instance;

Group 1 = $\mathit {A,B,C,D}$

Group 2 = $\mathit {H,I,J,K} $

Group 3 = $\mathit{M,N,O,P}$

Group 4 = $\mathit{X,Y,Z,T}$

NewGroup1 = $\mathit{A,H,M,X}$

NewGroup2 = $\mathit{B,I,N,Y}$

NewGroup3 = $\mathit{A,I,O,Z}$

...

How many NewGroups will be?

Note: I was thinking about applying a minimum colouring problem but this might turn out to be a NP-Hard problem. I also have in mind that to use permutation with repetition, but I am not sure it will give the correct result.

Comment: Try using Mathjax to format your question

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The example you provided helps explain the group process, but I am still confused as to what you are specifically looking for. Are you looking for the number of ways to form $1$ group such that it contains exactly $1$ member from each of the $4$ original groups? Instead, are you looking for the number of ways to form $4$ groups such that each contains exactly $1$ member from each of the $4$ original groups? Once you have specified the question you are asking, can you edit your post with the progress you have made toward solving the question?

Comment: @AlanAbraham Hello! I added couple of more examples to demonstrate the idea behind the problem that I am trying to seek a solution for it. I need every individual to meet each other, therefore it seems some kind of more general version of handshaking theorem, but with groups of people. There are 4 original groups, each group has 4 members. The people in the groups have already met each other.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a special case of a covering design; a collection of subsets of size $k=4$, from a set of size $v=16$, such that every group of size $t=2$ appears together in some subset. Looking at the [$(v,k,t)=(16,4,2)$ entry of the La Jolla Covering repository](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/show_cover.php?v=16&k=4&t=2), there is a solution using only $20$ groups, including the four initial groups. Here is the result, after some renaming and reorganizing to fit your problem.

Your particular problem can actually be solved by three orthogonal Latin squares of order four.

```
A, B, C, D, 
H, I, J, K,  
M, N, O, P, 
X, Y, Z, T, 

X, C, K, M, 
H, C, T, P, 
H, B, Z, O, 
H, A, X, N, 
H, D, M, Y, 
A, I, M, Z,
K, D, Z, P, 
B, K, Y, N, 
A, J, Y, P, 
J, C, Z, N, 
B, I, X, P, 
J, X, D, O, 
A, K, O, T, 
I, D, N, T,
I, C, Y, O, 
B, J, M, T,
```

Comment: I am very grateful for your answer! However,  I have got an issue in my mind, is there any generalization of this theorem, and what if I change the number of people in each group and also change the size of the new groups?

Comment: @dozgunay There aren't many general results I know if. I know that if there are initially $q$ groups of $q$, where $q$ is a prime power (in the original problem, $q=4=2^2$), then you can succeed with $q^2$ using mutually $q-1$ orthogonal Latin squares of order $q$.